# c# How to get the version of This current executable .exe

Tags: c#, version

I have been using this code to obtain my programs version:

```
public string progVersion = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
```

However, it doesn't always seem to grab the version I'm expecting. I don't really understand how this works entirely or what it's doing.

I think it is impart because I'm launching my program from another program  then it appears to grab the version of the program that launched it instead, or the 'GetExecutingAssembly()' I'm assuming references the program that executed my program, like so:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(my_programs_path);
```

Is there a more reliable way to get the program version of the actual program at the time I ask for it?

Perhaps even launch my program without leaving some kind of trail, as if the user themselves just launched it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm starting to think what I was experiencing was some kind of anomaly caused by something else, since I'm not able to replicate it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`GetExecutingAssembly()` returns the assembly that contains the method that calls it. If you call it from a library you will always get the version of the library not the application executable.

To get the application's executable use `GetEntryAssembly()`

Consider the following example:

In AssemblyA:

```
class VersionTest
{
  void Test()
  {
    Console.Write("Executing assembly: {0}\n", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().ToString()); // returns AssemblyA
    Console.Write("Entry assembly: {0}\n", Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().ToString());         // returns AssemblyB
  }
}
```

In AssemblyB:

```
class Program
{
   void Main()
   {
      var ver = new VersionTest();
      ver.Test();
   }
}
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `Assembly` property of a known type via `typeof` which is defined in your application to ensure you got the 'correct' assembly and then retrieve the version of that, e.g.

```
typeof(YourKnownType).Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString();
```

Comment: If the above code is in a class library assembly there is no way to know (or even have a reference to) a type in the main (.exe) application assembly. Thus it cannot be used to return the version of the application .exe

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for the great info.   I finally settled on

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString()
```

for my solution.